# области видимости и замыкание

Tags: javascript

Реализуйте функцию createCounter (initValue: number), которая работает следующим образом:

```
let counter = createCounter();
console.log(counter()); // 0
console.log(counter()); // 1
console.log(counter()); // 2
--------------------------------------
let counter = createCounter(13);
console.log(counter()); // 13
console.log(counter()); // 14
console.log(counter()); // 15*/
```

Как сделать, чтобы считало с нуля - я поняла. А вот с 13 уже проблемы. Что за (initValue: number) двоеточие в параметрах функции мне тоже непонятно.

```
function makeCounter() {   

    function counter() {  
        return counter.count++; 
    };

    counter.count = 0;  

    return counter;   
}

let counter = makeCounter(); 
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
```

Comment: Двоеточие это с typescriptа, указан тип передаваемого значение - число

Comment: Если вопрос про замыкание, то зачем counter.count вместо банальной переменной?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы можно было увеличивать от определенного числа, нам надо передавать собственно это число в функцию.

`initValue` уже будет у нас сохранена в `makeCounter`.
`makeCounter` возвращает функцию, которая увеличивает этот же `initValue`.

```js
let makeCounter=(initValue=0)=>()=>initValue++;

let c1 = makeCounter(); 
console.log(c1());
console.log(c1());
console.log(c1());
console.log(c1());

let c2 = makeCounter(13); 
console.log(c2());
console.log(c2());
console.log(c2());
console.log(c2());

console.log(c1());
console.log(c2());
```

---

Насчет двоеточия. Это способ указания типа значения в Typescript, которое должно передаваться в функцию. В нашем случае только число.

```js
function makeCounter(initValue: number = 0) {
  return function(): number {
    return initValue++;
  }
};

let c1 = makeCounter(2);

console.log(c1());
console.log(c1());
console.log(c1());
```

Comment: те присвоить  InitValue=0 нужно было в самих параметрах? в этом всё дело было?

Comment: Если вы не укажите 0 как дефолтный параметр, то каждый созданный каунтер будет начинатся от 0, потому что он там захардкодженный. Вам надо сделать этот 0 динамическим, чтобы там был не 0, а любое значение.

Comment: Посмотрите если не сложно, я добавила ответ. Так правильно будет?

Comment: @AliaTempora, правильно, но либо добавьте let counter, либо удалите его вообще и используйте initValue

Comment: @entithat Мы понимаем, почему нельзя 'объявлять' переменные без let / const в реальном коде. А у новичка при виде рабочего кода может возникнуть ложное представление, что так можно и нужно)

Comment: Согласен. А то уже подсознательно трактую СО как соревнования))

Answer (score 1):

```
function makeCounter(initValue = 0) {
    let count = initValue;
    return function () {
        return count++;
    };
    
}

let counter = makeCounter();
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
console.log(counter());
```

Comment: поправила
Вроде бы чуть понятнее стало, спасибо